# Github md + svg

Tags: css, github

Можно ли в файл readme.md на github закинуть svg или img, чтобы можно было к ним прописать стили css. Если да, то можете привести пример кода.
Заранее спасибки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) это облегчённый формат разметки и поддерживает совсем немного  возможностей. Подробнее про синтаксис можно почитать [там](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно прописать стили внутри сама svg, вот пример - [клик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342255/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-svg)

Далее можно svg закинуть в репозиторий github или в любое другое место, и в readme.md прописываем : `<img src="link svg">`